# ReactJS Iframe not loading page

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, aws-amplify

I'm using react to build a web-app. In one of my components is an Iframe element to load an external website. When I run the react-app on localhost, the Iframe loads the external site with no issues. When I deploy the app on AWS Amplify, the Iframe loads nothing, and I upon inspecting the element in the browser, under the properties of the Iframe, I get this message:

```
src:
[Exception: TypeError: Illegal invocation at HTMLIFrameElement.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:1:142)]
```

```
const body = (
    <div className={classes.modal}>
      <iframe className={classes.iframe} src={"http://www.website.com"}></iframe>
    </div>
  );
```

```
<Modal>
        {body}
</Modal>
```

Like I said, everything works when I run it on localhost, I just need to figure out why this Illegal Invocation error is happening. Does anyone know what is going on here? I've been looking stuff up for 2 hours with no progress. Thank you

Comment: Maybe, are you showing the iframe context with console.log()?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, 
My Amplify app is an https, and the content i'm trying to load is http, The browser simply will not allow http content to be loaded into an https page.